# custom horizontal scroll the list of images in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react. I have an array of image URLS. My Output was looking like this

Ouput Image Link: https://i.postimg.cc/nhWYvKpF/romantic-bell-wj2qss-Code-Sandbox.png

I don't want the scroll bar at bottom. I also don't need scrolls. My expected output was this.

Expected Output: https://i.postimg.cc/5tMjdjm5/Screenshot-from-2022-09-29-14-07-01.png

I want the left and right arrows for scrolling. I don't know how to make it in div. Please help me with some solutions.

Code SandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-bell-wj2qss?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you might want to check `carousel's` ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own carousel here is a good place to start from what you have

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-merkle-me25zv